# What is wrong with this producer consumer code?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I modified [an example with threads](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Python/0340__Thread/Multiplethreadsproducingconsumingvalues.htm)  and got the example with multiprocessing included below. My problem is that  ProduceToQueue ran fine, however ConsumeFromQueue did not finish. Why? This is one of my first multiprocessing programs, so be patient.

```
from Queue import Queue
import multiprocessing
import random
import time


class ProduceToQueue(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self, queue):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.shared_queue = queue

    def run(self):
        for i in range(11, 21):
            time.sleep(random.randrange(5))
            print "%s adding %s to queue" % (self.name, i)
            self.shared_queue.put(i)

        print self.name, "finished producing values"
        print "Terminating", self.name


class ConsumeFromQueue(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self, queue):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.shared_queue = queue

    def run(self):
        value = 0
        current = 10
        for i in range(10):
            time.sleep(random.randrange(3))
            print "%s attempting to read %s..." % (self.name, current + 1)
            current = self.shared_queue.get()
            print "%s read %s" % (self.name, current)
            value += current

            print "%s retrieved values totaling: %d" % (self.name, value)
            print "Terminating", self.name


queue = Queue()
producer = ProduceToQueue(queue)
consumer = ConsumeFromQueue(queue)

producer.start()
consumer.start()

producer.join()
consumer.join()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `multiprocessing` instead of `threading`, you should be using the `Queue` class from `multiprocessing` since it's the one that shares properly amongst processes. See [the Python docs on the multithreading module](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing) for details.

The standard `Queue` class (from `Queue`) will effectively be split into two *separate* queues whenever you create a child process. That means, in your situation, you have the queue in the main process (which nobody is touching), a *different* queue in the producer (which is being written to) and yet *another* queue in the consumer (which is being read from).

And there's no connection whatsoever between those three.

The quickest fix is to simply change:

```
from Queue import Queue
```

into:

```
from multiprocessing import Queue
```

so that your queues are of the correct type to work between processes rather than just threads. Or just get rid of that `from` line altogether and use:

```
queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
```

In addition (though I realise this is just play code), it's very unusual to have a sleep operation in the consumer, you would usually want to just keep that ready to roll for when a item appears on the queue.

Answer (score 3):

You're using `Queue.Queue`. For multiprocessing stuff you should use [`multiprocessing.Queue`](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue).

Comment: Thank you very much. Code is running fine now